# Do not get all the data i am trying to get from server

Tags: angular

My resolver -

```
class ProductsResolver implements Resolve<IProductInterface[]> {

  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<IProductInterface[]> {
    return this.productService.getProducts(
      +route.queryParamMap.get('gender')! as ProductGender,
      +route.queryParamMap.get('category')! as ProductCategory,
      );
  }
}
```

My component -

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._subscriptions.push(
      this.route.data.subscribe((data: Data) => {
        const products = data['products'] as IProductInterface[];
    
        this._products = products.map((product) => new Product(product));
    }));
  }
```

When I am console.log the `products` I get only some data and I can not see why.
That's what I get -

[image]

I am sure the product have `imageFileName` what is cause the problem?

edit -

```
export interface IProductInterface extends IDBCollectionInterface {
    readonly category: ProductCategory;
    readonly gender: ProductGender;
    readonly title: string;
    readonly description: string;
    readonly price: number;
    readonly imageFileName: string;
}

export class Product extends DBCollection {
    private _category: ProductCategory;
    private _gender: ProductGender;
    private _title: string;
    private _description: string;
    private _price: number;
    private _imageFileName: string;

    constructor(productData: IProductInterface) {
        super({
            id: productData.id,
            createdAt: productData.createdAt,
            updatedAt: productData.updatedAt,
        });

        this._category = productData.category;
        this._gender = productData.gender;
        this._title = productData.title;
        this._description = productData.description;
        this._price = productData.price;
        this._imageFileName = productData.imageFileName;
    }
```

Comment: Can you attach your `IProductInterface` interface and `Product` class to the question?

Comment: Did you confirm the network tab, by checking the response of the API call to see if imageFileName is existant within the array items?

Comment: Make sure that the `(data: Data)` returns the whole object that ypu want

Comment: @YongShun added